# How to Disable TortoiseGit "Do not show this message again" Setting

Tags: tortoisegit

In the TortiseGit Sync dialog box, after choosing "Fetch & Rebase," you are initially presented with a dialog box that has a "Do not show this message again" checkbox. If you check this, and later realize that you didn't like the option you chose, how do you bring back the dialog box so that you can choose a different option?

I've tried looking through the Settings dialogue box and all the git configuration files I can find, but the setting doesn't seem to be anywhere there. I've also tried uninstalling and re-installing TortoiseGit, but the setting persisted across the uninstall/reinstall.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Context menu -> TortoiseGit -> Settings -> Saved Data -> push `Stored decisions`'s `Clear` button.

See:

[image]

Note:

- This feature is introduced from 1.8.16.1 and related to [issue #2640](https://tortoisegit.org/issue/2640)
- Older than 1.8.16.1, you could delete some related registry key:

  - HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\TortoiseGit\**OpenRebaseRemoteBranchUnchanged**
  - HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\TortoiseGit\**OpenRebaseRemoteBranchFastForwards**

Comment: So is there any way to do it in earlier versions? The current version is 1.8.16.0, and I'd rather avoid upgrading my clients to preview versions if possible.

Comment: TortoiseGit 2.0 is coming. And I will edit the answer for pointint out which reg. you may want to delete for your situation.

Comment: Thank you for adding the registry key entries! That's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: TortoiseGit 2.0 is released.